# Typed<>/untyped design

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, generics

I have an (existing) typed class of items:

```
Items<T>
    T Value { get; }
```

T can be double, string or int.

I then have a class that has to hold several instances of Items. Within a single instance of this class, T is always the same. As it stands, the type actually contained is determined by a property and the container is not typed:

```
Data
    DataType { get; set; }
    Items<double>
        double Value;
    Items<string> 
        // ... and so on. Nasty stuff.
```

Ideally, of course, this would be

```
Data<T>
    Items<T>
        T value
```

Data instances are created from scratch in code, and can be loaded from a database. So of course a factory would be in our future, but what is the return type of the Create method?

Even worse, I need this:

```
DataCollection
    // HERE'S THE PAIN: What's the type here?
    List of Data<> instances with differing types

foreach (? data in someDataCollection)
    if (thetypeof data is double)
        doSomething();
    else
        doSomethingElse();
```

Now, I can solve this, but I can't see a CLEAN way to solve this.

My first issue is the declaration of DataCollection. What is the type of the list? List<object>, so it can hold Data<double> and Data<string>?

Comment: Please show actual code, not pseudo-code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually is a clean way to solve this; you can use a Dictionary with keys of the data type and values which are of type generic Func<> .  You then pass the type to your create method, which then looks up the Func<> to use in the Dictionary based on the type, and invokes that Func<> to create or process your object.

Since I am working from pseudo code, basically it would look something like the below; you can play with it and modify it to get it to serve your needs, but this is the basic idea.

First, create a parent class for all data objects; note that this class has a lookup dictionary for functions to invoke on various types, and note that it is abstract:

```
public abstract class Data
{

    // A Lookup dictionary for processing methods
    // Note this the functions just return something of type object; specialize as needed
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<object, Data>> _processFunctions = new Dictionary
        <Type, Func<object, Data>>()
         {
             {typeof(int), d => { return doSomethingForInt( (Data<int>) d); }},
             {typeof(string), d => { return doSomethingForString( (Data<string>) d); }},
             {typeof(double), d => { return doSomethingForDouble( (Data<double>) d); }},

         };

    // A field indicating the subtype; this will be used for lo
    private readonly Type TypeOfThis;

    protected Data(Type genericType)
    {
        TypeOfThis = genericType;
    }

    public Data Process()
    {
        return _processFunctions[this.TypeOfThis](this);
    }

}
```

Now subclass Data with a generic type that can be instantiated:

```
class Data<T> : Data
{

    // Set the type on the parent class
    public Data() : base(typeof(T))
    {
    }

    // You can convert this to a collection, etc. as needed
    public T Items { get; set; }

    public static Data<T> CreateData<T>()
    {
        return new Data<T>();
    }
}
```

You can then create a DataCollection class using the parent type.  Note the ProcessData() method; all it does now is loop over the elements and call Process() on each one:

```
class DataCollection
{
    public  IList<Data> List = new List<Data>();

    public void ProcessData()
    {
        foreach (var d in List)
        {
            d.Process();
        }
    }

}
```

...and you're all set! Now you can invoke your DataCollection with different types of Data:

```
DataCollection dc = new DataCollection();

dc.List.Add(new Data<int>());
dc.List.Add(new Data<string>());
dc.List.Add(new Data<double>());


dc.ProcessData();
```

Comment: Nice, but I'm still one level short: what does DataCollection look like?

Comment: More specifically, I need a collection that has a `Data<double>` and a `Data<string>` in it. I.e., that collection **does not have T**.

Comment: what happens if I do `Data<Foo> fooData = Data.CreateData<Foo>()` followed by `Data.Process(fooData);`

Comment: I've reworked the answer with working sample code and to address the DataCollection question.  Note that there isn't a simple answer since you want your collection to store types that do not have a common parent type...but this solution will work for you and is realitvely maintainable.  You can enable new types by adding a method to the `_processFunctions` dictionary, and you will receive an error if you try to invoke the `Process()` method on a type that is not registered (you can add graceful error handling).  You can't get true compile-time type checking, but this is the next best thing.

Comment: "you will receive an error if you try to invoke the Process()" What's the error you would receive?

Comment: You will get a `KeyNotFoundException` from the Dictionary because the type being used as a key is not registered.

Answer (score 1):

I think every time you need to do if-conditions on runtime data type, it means there's something wrong with the data structures. But every time I encounter situation like this, I have a hard time to solve it.

What I would try to do here is to wrap your primitive types into some kind of Adapters with conversion methods (possibly even implicit) and make all of them implement a common interface, let's say `IDoSomething`. Then, you can define the `doSomething` behaviors in `IntWrapper`, `DoubleWrapper` etc. separately. Then your `DataCollection` should be of type `List<IDoSomething>` and the loop can just call `data.DoSomething()` method from the interface.

<s>Having implicit conversion allows you to use the collection in the natural way like `data.Add(3)` - you'll still be able to add the items without wrapping the privitives</s>

Comment: `data.add(3)` won't work. You'd get a compile error of `Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'IDoSomething'` You'd still need to do `data.Add(IntWrapper(3))`